# How to use variable in Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I found Jenkins just ignore my variable `${BuildFolder}`, thanks for the help.

```
node {    
def BuildFolder = '/Build/${JOB_NAME}'+ '.' +'${BUILD_ID}'
stage ('prepare'){        
    sh "echo Build Folder: ${BuildFolder}"
    sh "rm -rf ${BuildFolder} && mkdir -p ${BuildFolder}"
}
stage ('Checkout'){
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
            extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
                relativeTargetDir: '${BuildFolder}']], 
            submoduleCfg: [], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '', 
            url: '']]])      
}
```

Comment: it is resolved by switching to "${BuildFolder}"

Answer (score -1):

You can create variables before the pipeline block starts. Then it should be work.

For Example,

```
def BuildFolder = '/Build/${JOB_NAME}'+ '.' +'${BUILD_ID}'

node 
{    
    stage ('prepare')
    {        
    sh "echo Build Folder: ${BuildFolder}"
    sh "rm -rf ${BuildFolder} && mkdir -p ${BuildFolder}"
    }
 }
```

Comment: it does not work:
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required   context class hudson.FilePath is missing
    Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node